# C# Async Issue - File Not Available - Waiting on Other Process to Finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

Ok, so I have the following procedure. When it comes to processing proc2, I get a fileLock error, which I think is due to proc1 still working on the file. How can I get proc2 to wait until proc1 is finished. Or at least at some control in proc1 to wait for a result?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String filePath = proc1();
        String result = proc2(filePath);
    }

private String proc1()
{
    // get a filePath
    String filePath = "C:\\Something.xml";
    String APIRequest = "SomeAPIRequest";
    DownloadAPI(filePath, APIRequest);
}

private static async void DownloadAPI(String filePath, String APIRequest, List<String> Parameters = null)
    {
    var client = new HttpClient();

    String APIString = APIRequest + "?ApiKey=" + APIKey;

    // Create the HttpContent for the form to be posted.
    var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("APIKey", APIKey),});

    // Get the response. Check for additional parameters required
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    if (Parameters != null)
    {
        foreach (String Parameter in Parameters)
        {
            APIString = APIString + "&" + Parameter;
        }
    }

    response = await client.PostAsync(APIString, requestContent);

    // Get the response content.
    HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

    StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath);

    // Get the stream of the content.
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
    {
        // Write the output.
        file.WriteLine((await reader.ReadToEndAsync()));
    }

    file.Close();
}

private String proc2(String filePath)
{
    // Do stuff with file here
    return "SomeString";
}
```

Comment: This problem mainly raises because the use of `async void`. Theres no way to determine if the method was completed successfully (missing Task as return type), so it'll just fire both methods at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async/await way:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var filePath = await proc1();
    var result = proc2(filePath);
}

private async Task<string> proc1() {
    // get a filePath
    var filePath = "C:\\Something.xml";
    var APIRequest = "SomeAPIRequest";
    await DownloadAPI(filePath, APIRequest);
    return filePath;
}

private static async Task DownloadAPI(string filePath, string APIRequest, List<string> Parameters = null) {
    // ...
}

private string proc2(string filePath) {
    // Do stuff with file here
    return "SomeString";
}
```

Comment: Cheers, that appears to have worked, thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

You need to await/wait on the DownloadApi call in proc1. Otherwise the control flow will continue onto calling proc2 before the DownloadApi call has completed.

Answer (score 0):

if it's one file you're working with, this is a more classical type of waiting solution.  The lock will wait till the first process is complete before letting in the second.

```
static object lockObj;

public void method()
{
  if(lockObj == null)
      lockObj = new object;

   lock(lockObj)
   {
     //wait your turn sensitive code here.
   }
}
```